# Dialogflow fulfillment - reset

Tags: deployment, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, inline-editor

I got a shocked when my in-line editor code is being reset to the default code by itself. However, it seems like the dialogflow chatbot is still functioning well with my code. I even tired to deploy the draft code I have saved to prevent such incident but it keep shows error when deploying.

What can I do or why is this happening?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZuwo.png

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this too. In our case it was because of an issue with the billing. Once we fixed the billing problem, our code appeared again in the editor.

## Where to find the code outside Dialogflow

The fulfillment uses Google Cloud Functions. You can find the source code in that section of the Google Cloud Console. Remember to select the correct project where your Dialogflow agent resides.

Navigate there, then you will see a list of Cloud Functions. Select the one for your agent, likely named "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment". Go into it and you will see tabs, one of which is "Source". From Source tab you can download the source code as a ZIP file.

You can't download this file if you have active billing problems.

## Fix billing problems

Go to the Google Cloud Console, navigate to billing (*or "Linked billing account" if asked*). Then you go to Payment Overview tab in the Overview section to see any issues. Resolve these.

You may have to go to the "Account management" section and click to re-enable billing after you fixed payment issue.